# How to use \ref Inside lstlistings

Tags: ref, lstlisting

How can I use `\ref` inside `lstlisting`.

I create two `lstlisting`s, e.g. `listing1` and `listing2`. Now, in the third `lstlisting`, I want to give a reference to them. But when I do, I do not get the reference of `listing1` and `listing2`.

Here is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Example 
"Listing 1": \ref={listing1},
"Listing 2": \ref{listing2}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

`listing1` and `listing2` are the labels I defined in other listings and they work fine when I reference them within the section.

Here is the output I am getting:

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site it is best to post full (but minimal) documents instead of sniplets like this. Full documents makes it easier for others to test. (3) Exactly why are you doing this? Listings has a very specific purpose, it might be that you should use a different solution here. (4) If you insist on using listings here, see the `escapeinside` option in the listings manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can define an `escapechar` (in my example it's `%`). Everything between two of these chars whill be interpreted as LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\%]
Example 
"Listing 1": %\label{listing1}%
"Listing 2": %\label{listing2}%
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I'm glad it helped @YasirSaleem! Please make sure to upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it works for you `:)`

Comment: I have marked the answer as accepted. But unfortunately, upvote does not work for me because of low reputation.

Comment: Oh don't worry about the upvote, but it is important to mark the answer that best works for you as accepted so others see that the question received a functioning reply.